# Flashing GPU vBios with another vendor's ROM

Tags: flash, gpu, bios, vendor

According to the VGA Bios Collection at TechPowerUp (https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/) the only BIOS ver. available from my GPU's vendor (Leadtek GTX 670 2GB) is incompatible with UEFI - needed for Fast Boots in some motherboard configs. Many other vendor's BIOS updates are UEFI compatible

Would it be incompatible, or rather disastrous, if a flash was ran with a BIOS from another GPU vendor [but similar GPU] ?

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to brick your device or make it extremely unstable. The probability of success will be related to how near the reference implementation both GPUs were designed. You'd also want a BIOS from a GPU as similar as possible to yours on every single specification, but there's not much prior art here.

Take a look at the [GTX 980 reference design](http://images.anandtech.com/doci/8526/NVIDIA_GeForce_GTX_980_FrontPCBCrop.jpg)

The RAM timings, bus width, fan controller, and any supporting general purpose chips on the board will likely be handled by the specific BIOS. If the GPU has any general purpose pins, those are also likely to break if you install the wrong vendor's BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

lunixbocs is right. It probably won't work anyway. The programming utility usually validated the PCI vendor ID and Devives ID, as well as the subsystem VID/DID.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this tool](http://www.win-raid.com/t892f16-AMD-and-Nvidia-GOP-update-No-requests-DIY.html) to integrate Nvidia GOP driver needed fror UEFI boot into your current VBIOS. Helped me a lot, worked 10+ times without any problem.